# How can I push my local git project to a remote server?

Tags: git

This is my scenario, I have two servers and my PC:

The origin project is on Remote Server A with git, I clone into my PC, I can edit this project and push to Remote Server A.

But now there is another requirement, that is I want to publish my project to Remote Server B in a directory such as `/www/wwwroot/`.

[image]

What should I do? how to set the git environment in Remote Server B/PC then I can use PC to push code to Remote Server B? 
Because in this case I can not clone from PC to Remote Server B, because the PC is a NAT address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To understand which `origin` have you configured for pushing to "Server A" do a `git remote get-url origin`.

Then check which can be the address of the "Server B" new origin and add it as a new origin like: `git remote add serverb https://serverb.com/gitrepo.git`.

Then whenever you would like to push to `serverb` do a `git push serverb <branch-name>`

Comment: Before this, you would first need to create `gitrepo` in server B and run `git init`.

Comment: That's a great addition in case he has the permission to create a git repo over there or just to push things to an existing repo without the possibility to clone/init a git repo. But for sure in case he has that kind of permission, he would need that step too.

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario

```
1.in server B /www/wwwroot:

#git init project_name
#cd project_name
#git config receive.denyCurrentBranch ignore

2.in PC push to serverB

#git remote add remote_14.193.1.1 root@14.193.1.1:/www/wwwroot/project_name/.git
#git push remote_14.193.1.1

3.in server B

#git reset --hard
```